# Can a homeowner's association take disciplinary action against traffic violations that occur on a city road that is the main artery?

Tags: california, driving

There is a road that goes through my community and is the only way for non-emergency motorized vehicles to enter. This road is owned by the city.
Assuming the HOA's regulations allow enforcement of traffic safety on this road, does state law allow the HOA to do so?

Comment: Enforcement of HOA regulations against members of the HOA or the general public or both? The road is owned by the city, is it safe to assume that the road is open to the public, i.e., it's not a gated community?

Comment: @Dave: Members. Also, this road is open to the public.